# Enforcing uniqueness on a relation based on a single column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a class method on my Consumer model that functions as a scope (acts on an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, can be daisy-chained) and returns doubles of some consumers.  I want it to only return unique consumers, and I can't seem to find either a way to do it with Rails helpers or the right SQL to pass in to get what I want.  I feel like there's a simple solution here - it's not a complicated problem.

I essentially want `Array#uniq`, but for `ActiveRecord::Relation`.  I tried a select DISTINCT statement

```
Consumer.joins(...).where(...).select('DISTINCT consumers.id')
```

It returned the correct 'uniqueness on consumers.id' property, but it only returned the consumer ids, so that when I eventually loaded the relation, the Consumers didn't have their other attributes.
Without select DISTINCT:

```
my_consumer = Consumer.joins(...).where(...).first
my_consumer.status  # => "active"
```

With select DISTINCT:

```
my_consumer = Consumer.joins(...).where(...).select('DISTINCT consumers.id').first
my_consumer.status  # => ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: missing attribute: status
```

I didn't think that an `ActiveRecord::Relation` would ever load less than the whole model, but I guess it will with the select statement.  When I query the Relation after the select statement for the class it contains, it returns `Consumer`, which seems strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.select('DISTINCT consumers.*')
```